# Google Charts: Hide points exceeding viewWindow

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart where I explicitly set the vertical-axis minimum and maximum

```
vAxis: {
  viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 0.20 },
},
```

Sometimes, the series to draw have values exceeding those values and the chart is rendered as follows:

[image: chart]

Is there an option I can define to hide what exceeds the ViewWindow? To get basically the chart below:

[image]

Comment: is the chart drawn in a hidden container and shown later?

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet to reproduce it?